# How to take multi-line input in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, multiline

I'm trying to take multi-line user input in Java and split the lines into an `array`, I need this to solve a problem for an online judge. I'm using a `Scanner` to take input. I cant determine the end of input. I always get an infinite loop, since I don't know the size of input (i.e number of lines)

Terminating input with an empty String (clicking enter) is still an infinite loop. Code provided below.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> in = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (s.hasNextLine() == true){
            in.add(s.nextLine());
            //infinite loop
        }
    }
```

I'm not even sure why the loop executes the first time. I believe the `hasNextLine()` should be false the first time ,since no input was taken yet. Any help or clarification appreciated.

Comment: Ctrl-Z perhaps?

Comment: You can determine an end line terminator character or string like "END" and when you get that input, you can finish the loop.

Comment: entering an empty string is still a form of input.. and for online judges, once all the input lines have been taken the loop will be exited

Comment: Also, FYI, when you call `hasNextLine()` the input has already been sent by the standard input. So when you see the program waiting for input, it's the standard input waiting. Then it sends its content to the scanner which, at this point, checks if a line is present. That's the reason why `hasNextLine` doesn't return immediately, even if you still didn't write anything to stdin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the empty line as a loop-breaker:

```
while (s.hasNextLine()){ //no need for "== true"
    String read = s.nextLine();
    if(read == null || read.isEmpty()){ //if the line is empty
        break;  //exit the loop
    }
    in.add(read);
    [...]
}
```

Comment: not works in ym case ... still receive two lines at one

Answer (score 1):

You could end the loop with something like below. Here, the String "END" (case-insenstive) is used to signify end of the multi-line content:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> in = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            in.add(line);

            if (line != null && line.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
                System.out.println("Output list : " + in);
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but since the input is coming from and Online Judge I don't think this will work

Comment: Ok, you could simply check for null or empty string instead of "END" and break the loop there. Above code is just an example :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. It returns when the user press `Enter` on an empty line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> arrayLines = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while(true){
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            if(line.equals("")){
                break;
            }
            else {
              System.out.println(line);
              arrayLines.add(line);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(arrayLines);
    }  
}
```

Best

Answer (score 1):

You can do somthing like this:

```
        while (s.hasNextLine() == true){
            String line = s.nextLine();
            if ("".equals(line)) {
                break;
            }
            in.add(line);
            //infinite loop
        }
```